# How you save a class object being used by another class in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, directory, filepath, save, nscoding

I'm making a Cookbook application for the iPad and iPod, and I have an array of my Recipe class in my Cookbook class.

```
@interface Cookbook : NSObject<NSCoding>{
NSMutableArray* recipes;
}
```

That's in my Cookbook class, and in my recipe class I have this:

```
@interface Recipe : NSObject<NSCoding>{
NSString* name;
NSMutableArray* ingredients; //List of ingredients for the recipe
UIImage* recipePicture;
NSMutableArray* instructions;
unsigned int prepTime;//in seconds
NSDate* dateAdded;
}
```

(I actually have more variables in here, but I didn't want to flood this with an excessive amount)

My problem is basically in the save/load feature. I've asked a similar question before here:
[How can I save an Objective-C object that's not a property list object or is there a better way for this than a property list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13327020/how-can-i-save-an-objective-c-object-thats-not-a-property-list-object-or-is-the)

This made me decide it'd be best to use NSCoding, and I've already implemented a method for it, too, in accordance with the way that was suggested with NSCoding.

My primary problem is that I can't get the recipes to be stored and successfully retrieved.

I've also had trouble getting the directory to my RecipeList.plist file to store the recipes in.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been the reason I can't continue making this application.

In my Cookbook.m I have:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
NSLog(@"Init With Coder - Cookbook");
if(self = [super init]){
    recipes = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"recipes"];
}
return self;
}
```

In my Recipe.m:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder{
if(self = [super init]){
    name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"name"];
    ingredients = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"ingreds"];
    recipePicture = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"recipePict"];
}
return self;
}
```

Once again, I have more variables in there, this is just for simplicity.
Also, this is my attempt at getting a file path to RecipeList.plist:

```
+(NSString*) filePath{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"RecipeList.plist"];

NSLog(@"%@",path);
return path;
}
```

My attempt at a save method in my AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void) save:(NSString *)path cookbook:(Cookbook *)cookbook{
BOOL b = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
NSLog(@"File exists: %i",b); //1 = exists, 0 = doesn't

NSMutableData* data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
if(data){ //If the data object was successfully initialized
    NSKeyedArchiver* archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    if(archiver){
        //Encode the recipe using the coder method defined in recipe.
        [archiver encodeInt:1 forKey:@"Version"];
        [archiver encodeObject:cookbook forKey:@"Cookbook"];
        [archiver finishEncoding];

        [data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}
}
```

and my load method:

```
-(Cookbook *) loadCookbook:(NSString *)path{
BOOL b = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path];
NSLog(@"File exists: %i",b);

Cookbook* ret = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
if(data){
    NSKeyedUnarchiver* unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
    int version = [unarchiver decodeIntForKey:@"Version"];
    if(version == 1){
        ret = (Cookbook*) [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"Cookbook"];
    }
    [unarchiver finishDecoding];
}
return ret;
}
```

I also have a save and load method for my Recipe class very similar to this.

Once again, any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you for taking the time to read through this.

EDIT: Here's the encodeWithCoder method in Recipe.m with a few variables omitted for the sake of brevity:

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
NSLog(@"Encoding Recipe.");
[aCoder encodeObject:name forKey:@"name"];
[aCoder encodeObject:ingredients forKey:@"ingreds"];
[aCoder encodeObject:recipePicture forKey:@"recipePict"];
[aCoder encodeObject:instructions forKey:@"instructs"];
[aCoder encodeObject:category forKey:@"categ"];
[aCoder encodeObject:dateAdded forKey:@"dateAdd"];
[aCoder encodeInt:prepTime forKey:@"prepTime"];

}
```

and in Cookbook.m:

```
-(void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder{
NSLog(@"Encoding cookbook.");
[aCoder encodeObject:recipes forKey:@"recipes"];
}
```

Comment: You save it from your save button, retrive it from your open button action, no matter how many classes are accessing it. If you want threadsafe then you can opt for atomic, however atomic is not fully thread safe.

Comment: Maybe off topic, but I would use core data. This would then be a easy as pie :)

Comment: Aside from your image, it appears that everything is pretty much a string or int or date, or an array or dictionary of the same.  JSON is a pretty good fit to this -- you'd have to special-case the image, and the date to a small degree, but the strings and numbers and arrays and dictionaries are pretty much automatic.

Comment: What's in your `encodeWithCoder:` implementations?

Comment: Have a look at my answr in this, writing object to file and reading back, you may feel it handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13801222/save-array-of-objects-with-properties-to-plist/13801425#13801425

Comment: Sorry but the code is long to see, I haven't read everything, are you asking just how to do it or there's a part of the code that doesn't work?

Comment: It'd be a shame to see you cease development on your project. You haven't presented it all, of course, but it seems as though it wants for only a detail or two. I was one of those who upvoted fguchelaar's comment: Have you provided a full implementation of NSCoder protocol for your objects?

Comment: I'd also like to say that I don't think it makes any sense to tear down what you've done just to implement it using Core Data. Core Data isn't a panacea for everything, as some might infer.

Comment: I'll update my question with an encodeWithCoder: method at the end, and I'll look into your explanations/answers, Anoop.

Comment: And to Ramy: Sometimes when I experiment with different ways to get the filepath, the program just crashes. As for my primary concern, I just can't get the data I save to be reloaded. I feel like a big part of the problem is actually the path I'm trying to save it to, RecipeList.plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've "almost" copy-pasted your code and after some minor adjustments I've got it up and running.

To the Cookbook, I've added:

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        recipes = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and

```
- (void)addRecipe:(Recipe *)recipe {
    [recipes addObject:recipe];
}
```

You might have those already? I assume you're instantiating the array somewhere?

Then using this test-routine, the cookbook is created, used and saved perfectly fine:

```
NSString *path = [self filePath];
Cookbook *cookbook = [self loadCookbook:path];

if (cookbook) {
    NSLog(@"Loaded cookbook: %@", cookbook);
}
else {
    cookbook = [[Cookbook alloc] init];
}

Recipe *recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];
recipe->name = @"The name";
[cookbook addRecipe:recipe];

[self save:path cookbook:cookbook];
NSLog(@"Saved cookbook: %@", cookbook);
```

**fyi**: I've made the Recipe's instance variables @public for brevity; hopefully you're using accessors (@property).

Do you use Automatic or Manual reference counting?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late response, but I'm currently using Automatic Reference Counting. I'll try your suggestion tomorrow as soon as I can and let you know how it goes. I really appreciate the help (I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while and found that I literally couldn't get much more accomplished without perfecting this feature first-- the most important feature by far).

Comment: I've tried it out, and for some reason my NSLog(@"file exists: %i",b)  statement in my loadCookbook: method always says that the file RecipeList.plist doesn't exist. That would seem to be the core of my problem at this point; however, I could be wrong.

Comment: The I'd suggest to write a small piece of code that just creates a file at your designated location. See if that works... You can check the contents of the simulators filesystem at ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<VERSION>/Applications/<ID>/